# Why does my Flutter app crash when attempting to launch Apple Maps?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am attempting to launch Apple Maps using Launch and a Url, only thing is that it crashes with no error message and I'm not sure why. The Url looks like so: http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=&daddr=
I check if it's Android or ios and build out the urls like this

```
                              if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                                 {
                                  await launch("$androidURL${widget.name} ${widget.city}, ${widget.state}");
                              }
                              } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
                                await launch("$iosURL${widget.name} ${widget.city}, ${widget.state}");
                              }
                            }
```

It has worked in the past but doesn't seem to work anymore. Right after it hits the line to build the url and launch maps it loses connection to the emulator and stops, how do I prevent this and just have it open maps as intended? Attached below is my flutter doctor. If I left any essential info out let me know and I'llm include it. Thanks all! [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have done the configurations that are needed to use the url_launcher plugin, you can  try

```
await canLaunch(_url) ? await launch(_url) : throw 'Could not launch $_url';
```

This way you can at least identify the error;